# How to resolve keyboard shortcut collision between browser and online editor?

Tags: google-chrome, key-bindings, plunker

Some online editor is handy to use, such as plunker. They also provide keybindings such as for emacs/vim.

However, editor hotkey such as Ctrl-n (next line) collide with Chrome browser hotkey (new window).

Is there a way to resolve this?